# Retrieving video frames using opencv - unhandled exception

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am getting video frames using `cvQueryframes`, but in few videos of `avi` file I get :

```
Unhandled exception at 0x715c14f0 0xC0000005: 
    Access violation reading location 0x02f509f0.
```

I am using visual studio 2010 with `OpenCV 2.4.5` and `Qt5`

```
CvCapture* cap= cvCaptureFromFile(file);
frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
```

Comment: You need to be more specific. Showing code would help, because it seems you're doing something unsafe like reading outside the bounds of an array.

Comment: Please add more points to your question.. Its wage.

Comment: What does your debugger say?

Comment: CvCapture* cap= cvCaptureFromFile(file); frame = cvQueryFrame(capture); code where i get exception

Comment: I suppose you misspelled `cap` or `capture`. You should check the return value of `cvCaptureFromFile` which would be `NULL` if you're trying to open a file not supported by [`VfW`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_for_Windows).

Comment: sorry i wrongly typed i am using capture only in both place

Answer (score 0):

There could be multiple reasons for this, link wrong file name, codec not found etc. Try putting debug printf before opening file to see if file name is proper also check for cap if it is not NULL. You can try something like this

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{

    char *my_file = "C:\\vid_an2\\desp_me.avi";
    std::cout<<"Video File "<<my_file<<std::endl;
    cv::VideoCapture input_video;

    if(input_video.open(my_file))
    {
         std::cout<<"Video file open "<<std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout<<"Not able to Video file open "<<std::endl;

    }
    namedWindow("My_Win",1);
    namedWindow("Segemented", 1);
    Mat cap_img;
    for(;;)
    {
         input_video >> cap_img;
         imshow("My_Win", cap_img);
          waitKey(0);
    }
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: thanks for ur nice answer i ll try and let u know, i already checked whether file is null or not, anyway thank u so much

Comment: Note that you're using the C++ interface of OpenCV while the OP is using the C interface.

Comment: Yes the above is C++ interface. Also I would recommend to check if there is some other application using CAM. if yes then it would be better to close it first.

Comment: the above code throws a exception, "Unhandled exception at 0x754bc6e3 in OpenCVTestApp.exe: Microsoft C++ exception: cv::Exception at memory location 0x001df568.." please help i am further confused

Comment: The above code was meant for test purpose. You will need to change the file name("C:\\vid_an2\\desp_me.avi";) to different one present on your system. If it doesn't work then try to load a simple jpg image using OpenCV to make sure that your opencv installation is correct else you would need to reinstall your opencv.